# $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left|e^{iθ}-α\right|^{2}} \,dθ=\frac{2\pi}{1-|α|^{2}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

Set $\alpha\in\mathbb{C},\,|\alpha|<1.$ Show the following:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\left|e^{ix}-\alpha\right|^{2}} \,dx=\dfrac{2\pi}{1-|\alpha|^{2}}$$
**Solution:**
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\left|e^{ix}-\alpha\right|^{2}}\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\left(e^{ix}-\alpha\right)\left(e^{ix}-\overline{\alpha}\right)}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{i}\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{i\cdot e^{ix}}{\left(e^{ix}-\alpha\right)\left(e^{ix}-\overline{\alpha}\right)}\,dx
\end{equation*}
Set $z=e^{ix}$ and $dz=ie^{ix}dx$
\begin{equation*}
\Rightarrow\;\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\left|e^{ix}-\alpha\right|^{2}}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{i}\int_1^{e^{2\pi i}}\dfrac{1}{(z-\alpha)(1-\overline{\alpha}\cdot z)}\,dz
\end{equation*}
Set $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{1-\overline{\alpha}\cdot z}$ and $f\in Ο\left(\mathbb{C}\backslash\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\right),\;\;|\alpha|<1\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\left|\overline{\alpha}\right|}>1$
$$\Rightarrow\;\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\left|e^{ix}-\alpha\right|^{2}}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{i}\int_1^{e^{2\pi i}}\dfrac{f(z)}{z-\alpha} \,dz$$
**How do I procced?**

Comment: When you let $z = e^{ix}$ on an integral with period $2\pi$, you don't plug in the bounds. You have to transform your integral into a contour integral over the unit circle so you can proceed.

Comment: As @Accelerator notes, instead of $\int_1^{e^{2\pi i}}$ you want a contour integration symbol, $\oint_{|z|=1}$. In your notation, the result is $2\pi i\times f(\alpha)/i=2\pi f(\alpha)$ (hint: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) if the $2\pi i$ factor is unfamiliar). Note in particular no pole at $z=1/|\alpha|$ contributes, because it's outside the region the contour encloses.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\left|e^{ix}-a\right|^{2}} \,dx\\
=& \int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{2}{(e^{ix}-a) (e^{-ix}-\bar a)} \,dx\\
= &\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{2}{1-2|a|\cos x+|a|^2} \,dx \>\>\>\>\>t =\tan\frac x2\\
=&\int_0^\infty\frac2{(1+|a|)^2\ t^2 + (1-|a|)^2}dt
=  \frac{2\pi}{1- |a|^2}
\end{align}